# Reduce Javascript object array to string

Tags: javascript

I want to map item to quantity, like this `item: quantity`.

Assuming I have an object array:

```
{
  Item: "",
  Quantity : 2,
},
{
  Item: "B",
  Quantity : 7,
},
{
  Item: "",
  Quantity : "",
}
]
```

I should get the following string output

```
`: 2, B: 7`
```

I have tried the basic for loop and if conditions way like below but I want something shorter

```
var str = "";
for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
  str += array[a].Item + ",";
  str += array[a].Quantity;
  if (a != array.length - 1) {
    str += ",";
  }
}
```

Comment: you have no `null` values. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: do you means `empty` values?

Comment: @HarshPatel yes, `empty` stirng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values and join them.

```js
var array = [{ Item: "", Quantity: 2 }, { Item: "B", Quantity: 7 }, { Item: "", Quantity: "" }],
    string = array
        .filter(({ Item, Quantity }) => Item || Quantity)
        .map(({ Item, Quantity }) => `${[Item ? Item : "", Quantity ? Quantity: ""].join(': ')}`)
        .join(', ');
    
console.log(string);
```

Comment: why filter first and then check again for mapping? the filter out object need no more checking, because they are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Using array.reduce() would be a better and cleaner approach.

```
let arr = [{ Item: "", Quantity: 2 }, { Item: "B", Quantity: 7 }, { Item: "", Quantity: "" }]
```

```
const groupBy = arr.reduce(function (total, obj) 
               { 
                 total += (obj.Item + ":" + (obj.Quantity + " , ")); 
                 return total; 
                }, 0);
```